# How can I give condition in where() function to get not equal to zero record in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have one `Grand total` column in my table and I want to show only greater then `zero(0)` number records in my table

I try like this in `model`

```
function fetchCashDetail($from_date_bk,$to_date_bk,$lr_pay_mode){

    $this->db->select('*')
          ->from('delivery_due_received')
          ->where('delivery_due_date BETWEEN "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from_date_bk)). '" AND "'. date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to_date_bk)).'"');

    if($lr_pay_mode == 'pending'){ 
        $this->db->where('g_total !==0');
    }else{
        $this->db->where('pay_mode',$lr_pay_mode);
    }                                     
    return $this->db->get()->result();
}
```

And it returns `Unknown column '=0' in 'where clause'` this error message
I want to show only greater then zero numbers.

Comment: Are you sure that `g_total !==0` is a valid expression for whatever ORM you are using?

Comment: Try `!=` instead of `!==` as thats PHP syntax not MySQL

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks its working

Answer (score 2):

```
$this->db->where('g_total != 0');
```

`!==` is not a valid expression

Or even better:   `$this->db->where('g_total !=', 0);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->where('g_total >',0);
```

You can try this